# PHP not retaining Javascript changes

Tags: php

I have this simple javascript function which changes the body zoom of the web page. The function runs properly when I am having it on a HTML page as a normal javascript. When I embed it in PHP, it is not retaining the body zoom change. The javascript embedded in PHP can be shown as follows:

```
<?php
?>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function zoomout()
{
document.body.style.zoom = screen.width/1024;
document.body.style.zoom = screen.height/1024;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="test">
<center>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="zoomout()">1024</button>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here. Thanks

Comment: Firstly, your form and center tags are not properly nested. You have <form><center></form></center>. The other thing I can think of might be whether your web server is actually engaging the PHP processor so that the <?php> tags get stripped as they should.

Comment: What's not normal about this javascript? If you call this script via php, be sure you use echo('Your script HERE');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try taking the form tags out.  You really don't need them if you aren't submitting something somewhere

Comment: yes...that was the solution. How silly of me, thanks a lot rogerlsmith...:)

Comment: correctly, whenever you press the button the page reloads! this will cause the zoom not to be retained.

Comment: It should only reload if the form has an action.  Otherwise simply running some javascript shouldn't cause the page to reload.

Comment: Reloading has to do with `submit`-type input, not `action`-attribute. There're no submits here.